# scraping website for '__hpKey' and then logging in using requests and beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, forms-authentication

This is my first coding project, so I might not have got all the terminology right. I am trying to login into the NHS blood donation website with the requests and BeautifulSoup libraries in python. I have managed to do this, but it only works when I use a value for '__hpKey' which I have copied and pasted from the Login Headers from the networks tab in my browser. I'd like to be able to scrape the website to find this token and not have to use the token which I have copied and pasted.

I have managed to find '__hpKey', but this key doesn't seem to work when trying to login.

```
s = requests.session()
soup_key = BeautifulSoup(s.get('https://my.blood.co.uk/Account/SignIn').content, 'html.parser')
key = soup_key.find('input', {'name': '__hpKey'})['value']
```

I have just been putting the value from the networks login tab where 'key' is as using the code above doesn't login successfully. I have narrowed down the four elements I need to pass through to the login portal. These are:

```
data = {
  'LoginEmailAddress': 'email',
  'LoginPassword': 'password',
  'Question-Reason': '',
  '__hpKey': 'key'                ## 'key' is a 216 character key ending in ==
```

I then pass these 4 elements through to the login portal and use BeautifulSoup to parse the title of the webpage with my donor profile on. The title lets me know if it has logged in successfully.

```
login_req = s.post('https://my.blood.co.uk/Account/Login', data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get('https://my.blood.co.uk/Home/Landing?load=Yourdonations').content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title)       # If logged in prints "My Donor Record", else prints "My Donor Record - Sign in or Register"
```

So, how do I go about finding a value of '__hpKey' which works when passed through to the login portal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some validation fields to include in the requests. Those fields are located in the hidden `input` tag of the form. The quickest way is to get all input under the form and send all of them as is in the payload :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

email = "your@email.com"
password = "your_password"

r = s.get("https://my.blood.co.uk/Account/SignIn")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
form = soup.findAll("form")[1]

payload = dict([
    (t["name"],t["value"]) 
    for t in form.findAll("input")
    if t.has_attr("value")
])
payload["Type-Fax"] = "" # maybe not necessary ?
payload["LoginEmailAddress"] = email
payload["LoginPassword"] = password

print(payload)
r = s.post("https://my.blood.co.uk/Account/Login", data = payload)

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get('https://my.blood.co.uk/Home/Landing?load=Yourdonations').content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title)
```

Note that I've not tested the above code with a valid account